# Can't connect to TitanDB - A Titan graph with the same instance id [] is already open. Might required forced shutdown

Tags: java, titan, gremlin

Everything worked well until after a shutdown of my application server I could not connect to TitanDB.
My connection code:

```
try {
      titanGraph = TitanFactory.build()
                   .set("storage.backend", "cassandra")
                   .set("storage.hostname", titanHostname)
                   .set("graph.unique-instance-id-suffix", 99)
                   .open();
            if(titanGraph.isOpen()) {
                LOGGER.info("Success to open Titan DB");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            initError(e, "Error opening Titan DB: ");
        }
```

I always get this exception:

```
Caused by: com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanException: A Titan graph with the same instance id [c0a838012r] is already open. Might required forced shutdown.
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.<init>(StandardTitanGraph.java:133)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:93)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$Builder.open(TitanFactory.java:134)
    at com.ngsoft.security.auth.TitanLoginModule.connectTitanDB(TitanLoginModule.java:119)
    ... 33 more
```

the main issue is:

**A Titan graph with the same instance id [...] is already open. Might required forced shutdown.**

Reboot my pc & the cassandra cluster didn't worked

Comment: Also, you should make sure to close the TitanGraph when your application server goes down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example for how to remove session id **c0a838012r** from the database:

we need to access the management system via **gremlin**, remove the instance and commit.

```
         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(_)-oOOo-----
gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open('../conf/titan-db.properties')
==>titangraph[cassandra:[10.20.30.11, 10.20.30.12]]
gremlin> mgmt = g.getManagementSystem()
==>com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem@c1fca2a
gremlin> mgmt.getOpenInstances()
==>c0a838019904-Yossi_c-pc1
==>c0a838012r
==>c0a838016736-Yossi_c-pc1
gremlin> mgmt.forceCloseInstance('c0a838012r')
==>null
gremlin> mgmt.commit()
==>null
```

Comment: for janusgraph-0.3.1-hadoop2, I use `graph.openManagement()` to get mgmt.